# Angular any way to catch event once in a child component generated with *ngFor which subscribed to changes in a service?

Tags: angular

I have a component `A` and different `B` components which are generated using `*ngFor` and a service (`A` and `B` are not siblings and live on different levels). Each of `B` components are subscribed to changes on a certain field in a service. Component `A` makes a change in the service and the subscription event is caught in every `B` component (if there are 10 `B` components, the event will be caught 10 times). I'm not sure if this behavior is normal. If it isn't, is there a way to receive the event only once?

Parent HTML creating `B` components:

```
<comp-B [step]="step" *ngFor="let step of steps"></comp-B>
```

Service:

```
  private stepSelectedSub = new Subject<any>();
  public stepSelectedSubObservable$ = this.stepSelectedSub.asObservable();
  
  constructor() { }

  public stepSelected(selectedStep: any) {
    this.stepSelectedSub.next(selectedStep);
  }
```

The looped over `B` component:

```
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private stepsService: StepsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.stepsService.stepSelectedSubObservable$.subscribe(newStepSelected => {
      console.log(newStepSelected); //printed for every child component there is
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably `filter`, because in your `B` components, you are only interested in the events that occur due to changes to that particular property that B is handling, so something like this should help:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription = this.stepsService.stepSelectedSubObservable$.pipe(
    filter(step => /* only step that matters for this particular instance of B */),
  ).subscribe(newStepSelected => {
    console.log(newStepSelected);
  });
}
```